# how to cutdown the cloudwatch metrics cost that occurs on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops

While analysing the cost report of AWS, I have noticed that , cloudwatch metrics is incurring cost of $3.73 . I have deployed microservice on ECS EC2 instance via dynamic port mapping. I dont know for what reason it occurs , eventhough the detailed monitoring and container insights is disabed.

It will be great, if anyone provide information for which reason and how this can be cut it down on AWS cost.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-understand-and-reduce-charges/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.